# How to use SSH tunnel in ansible to provide internet access to a server

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, ansible

We have few servers in a DC which are not connected to the internet (accessible only via vpn), Sometimes we need to update the time in servers using htpdate, Right now we do it by creating a ssh tunnel and squid proxy (see below commands)

```
ssh root@192.168.30.10 -R3128:localhost:3128 
export http_proxy='http://localhost:3128' 
htpdate -da -l -P localhost:3128 3.in.pool.ntp.org 1.asia.pool.ntp.org 3.asia.pool.ntp.org
export http_proxy=' '
```

How can I automate this with ansible ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not about programming as required for Stackoverflow. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has suggestions for other SE sites where this question may be appropriate.

Comment: stackoverflow have most number of ansible questions than any other sub communities like server fault/unix & linux, that's why asked here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add any SSH args via `ansible_ssh_extra_args` or companions (see [doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters)).

Inventory:

```
remote-host ansible_host=192.168.30.10 ansible_ssh_extra_args="-R3128:localhost:3128"
```

Playbook:

```
- hosts: remote-host
  environment:
    http_proxy: http://localhost:3128
  tasks:
    - command: htpdate -da -l -P localhost:3128 3.in.pool.ntp.org 1.asia.pool.ntp.org 3.asia.pool.ntp.org
```

Comment: ansible_ssh_extra_args= was the magic sauce I am missing , Thank you :)

Comment: How can I unset http_proxy after running htpdate command in same playbook ?

Comment: If you need proxy only for single task, use `environment` only for that task.